# Caffe Installation - Can't Start Compilation

Tags: ubuntu, compiler-errors, installation, makefile, caffe

I am installing it without cuda support... I don't have nVidia graphics card...

`shivangpatel@shivangpatel-Inspiron-1464:~/caffe$ make
Makefile:295: *** Cannot static link with the /usr/bin/gcc-4.7 compiler.  Stop.`

I have gcc-4.7 and gcc-4.8. I tried with both using alternative options.... Then i tried cmake

cmake :

```

```
shivangpatel@shivangpatel-Inspiron-1464:~/caffe/build$ cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.4
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.7.3
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/gcc-4.7
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/gcc-4.7 -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Boost version: 1.54.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   system
--   thread
--   filesystem
-- Looking for include file pthread.h
-- Looking for include file pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Found GFlags: /usr/include  
-- Found gflags  (include: /usr/include, library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgflags.so)
-- Found Glog: /usr/include  
-- Found glog    (include: /usr/include, library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglog.so)
-- Found PROTOBUF: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so  
-- Found PROTOBUF Compiler: /usr/bin/protoc
-- Found HDF5: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_hl.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5.so  
-- Found LMDB: /usr/include  
-- Found lmdb    (include: /usr/include, library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblmdb.so)
-- Found LevelDB: /usr/include  
-- Found LevelDB (include: /usr/include, library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libleveldb.so)
-- Found Snappy: /usr/include  
-- Found Snappy  (include: /usr/include, library: /usr/lib/libsnappy.so)
CMake Warning at cmake/Dependencies.cmake:63 (message):
  -- CUDA is not detected by cmake.  Building without it...
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:38 (include)


-- OpenCV found (/usr/share/OpenCV)
-- Found Atlas: /usr/include  
-- Found Atlas (include: /usr/include, library: /usr/lib/libatlas.so)
-- Found PythonInterp: /home/shivangpatel/env/bin/python2.7 (found suitable version "2.7.6", minimum required is "2.7") 
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so (found suitable version "2.7.6", minimum required is "2.7") 
-- Found NumPy: /home/shivangpatel/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include (found suitable version "1.10.4", minimum required is "1.7.1") 
-- NumPy ver. 1.10.4 found (include: /home/shivangpatel/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include)
-- Boost version: 1.54.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   python
-- Could NOT find Doxygen (missing:  DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE) 
-- Found Git: /usr/bin/git (found version "1.9.1") 
-- 
-- ******************* Caffe Configuration Summary *******************
-- General:
--   Version           :   <TODO> (Caffe doesn't declare its version in headers)
--   Git               :   rc2-753-gcff6f3d
--   System            :   Linux
--   C++ compiler      :   /usr/bin/gcc-4.7
--   Release CXX flags :   -O3 -DNDEBUG -fPIC -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-uninitialized
--   Debug CXX flags   :   -g -fPIC -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-uninitialized
--   Build type        :   Release
-- 
--   BUILD_SHARED_LIBS :   ON
--   BUILD_python      :   ON
--   BUILD_matlab      :   OFF
--   BUILD_docs        :   ON
--   CPU_ONLY          :   OFF
--   USE_OPENCV        :   ON
--   USE_LEVELDB       :   ON
--   USE_LMDB          :   ON
--   ALLOW_LMDB_NOLOCK :   OFF
-- 
-- Dependencies:
--   BLAS              :   Yes (Atlas)
--   Boost             :   Yes (ver. 1.54)
--   glog              :   Yes
--   gflags            :   Yes
--   protobuf          :   Yes (ver. 2.5.0)
--   lmdb              :   Yes (ver. 0.9.10)
--   LevelDB           :   Yes (ver. 1.15)
--   Snappy            :   Yes (ver. 1.1.0)
--   OpenCV            :   Yes (ver. 2.4.8)
--   CUDA              :   No
-- 
-- Python:
--   Interpreter       :   /home/shivangpatel/env/bin/python2.7 (ver. 2.7.6)
--   Libraries         :   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so (ver 2.7.6)
--   NumPy             :   /home/shivangpatel/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.10.4)
-- 
-- Documentaion:
--   Doxygen           :   No
--   config_file       :   
-- 
-- Install:
--   Install path      :   /home/shivangpatel/caffe/build/install
-- 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/shivangpatel/caffe/build
```

`Now, After`make all```

```

```
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libcaffe.so
[ 87%] Built target caffe
Scanning dependencies of target caffe.bin
[ 87%] Building CXX object tools/CMakeFiles/caffe.bin.dir/caffe.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable caffe
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/caffe.bin.dir/caffe.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol '__cxa_free_exception@@CXXABI_1.3'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [tools/caffe] Error 1
make[1]: *** [tools/CMakeFiles/caffe.bin.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

```

Please anyone give the solution... Where is mistake ! 
I am attaching ny Makefile.config
[make_config.txt](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/files/84085/make_config.txt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the compiler is missing a linking instructions.

[This](http://codeyarns.com/2014/05/02/undefined-reference-error-with-__cxa_free_exceptioncxxabi_1-3/) SO question deals with a similar linking error.

And [this](http://codeyarns.com/2014/05/02/undefined-reference-error-with-__cxa_free_exceptioncxxabi_1-3/) blog post also.

The quick solutions is passing `-lstdc++` to the linker.